# Javascript Constructor with curly {} brackets

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am new to javascript. I am looking at pre-written code. I do not understand what is in the curly brackets:
 {constructor({parts, tools, database})

```
class MyMenu {
  constructor({parts, tools, database}) 
 {
     ...
    this.database = database;   
    this.tools = this._myTools(tools);
    this.parts = this._myParts(parts);
    ..
 }

some code here

functions()
...
...
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called destructuring. e.g.

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// you can get value of a using destructuring like this

const { a } =  obj;

console.log(a);

// Similarly, this applies to function arguments

//e.g.

const personData = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 20 };


class Person {
   constructor ({ firstName, lastName, age }) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.age = age;
   }
}

const person = new Person(personData);

console.log(person.firstName);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hamid kindly mark the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is object destructuring:
https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#simulating-named-parameters-in-javascript

Investigate paragraph 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

This is destructuring, and it is an awesome feature!

```
o = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}
const {key2} = o
console.log(key2)
```

It is essentially a way of pulling elements out of objects, without having to traverse the whole object.